# Build Events - Shortcuts with names

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Want to move one project's files as needed into another project's Output.

```
xcopy /y "$(SolutionDir)..\db\dbw.sdf" "$(SolutionDir)Shell\$(OutDir)"
```

Instead of the 2nd part want to use something similar to this :

but It's said `"exited with code 4"`

**Where Are they : (Folder Structure)**

**Top Dir** : Solution,DB,Src

**Shell** (The Main Project Name) : is located in the Src

*dbw File is located in `ProjectX` want to move it into Shell Project's Output dir.*

What could be the Shortest possible form of passing this address ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you're trying to do... what is "Shell"? A sub-directory of `$(SolutionDir)`  ?

Comment: It's the main project. Named : Shell.

Comment: So you actually want the post build event to copy a file which is outside of the solution dir into a specific directory inside your project? Whats wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @Blachshma I edited the post, please review it, Does this support anyway using "Project Names" as some shorthands ? What shortest form or shortcut do you know to this ? My real project is a lot bigger than this and I wanted to know any other option which I could have.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question, is this what you want?

`xcopy "$(SolutionDir)..\db\dbw.sdf" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)dbw.sdf" /Y`

?

Here is a list of all the [PostBuild macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), if this is not what you're looking for - maybe it can help.

Comment: No friend, These are much harder, Here Using Prism, I have to put one project's files in other projects OutDir. The story happens a lot. and this is just a sample.

Comment: I was wrong that didn't work for me, $(Shell) exited with code 4. Edit my post in a minute to point it out clearly and simply.

Comment: Really don't understand why that happens, That happened to me alot, One time it gives you error and on the 2nd run it executes!

Comment: Updated, use xcopy <source> <target> /Y and **not**: xcopy /y <source> <target>